# написание фразы (правописание частиц не и ни)

Tags: грамотная-речь, не-или-ни

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли написана следующая фраза "у нас с этим человеком не единый путь(в том смысле, что с этим человеком у нас разные пути)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***У нас с этим человеком не единый путь.***

**Отрицательная** частица НЕ относится к сочетанию ***единый путь*,** написание **раздельное**.

Но стилистика предложения не очень корректная, лучше сказать так:

***У нас с этим человеком нет единого пути.***